# removeTextChangedListener on focus lost

Tags: java, android

I'm calling an *onFocusChange* method in a EditText, inside the method, when the field has the focus I call *addTextChangedListener* with a previously declared *TextWatcher* to the same field.
When the field lose focus I remove the *TextWatcher*.
But it look like not working, because in a second field I eventually need to set the text to the first field and it end with calling the *TextWatcher* that I previously removed.

```
    et1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            final TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    // Do things
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // Do things
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // Do things
                }
            };

            if (hasFocus) {
                et1.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
            } else {
                et1.removeTextChangedListener(watcher);
            }
        }
```

Then here start the code for the second field (using similar logic)

```
    et2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            final TextWatcher watcherEt2 = new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    // Do things
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // Do things
                   et1.setText("from things"); //here the removed TextWatcher is runned
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // Do things
                }
            };

            if (hasFocus) {
                et2.addTextChangedListener(watcherEt2);
            } else {
                et2.removeTextChangedListener(watcherEt2);
            }
        }
```

It's an Android Studio bug, or i miss something?

Comment: Why don't you simply want  to `addTextChangedListener` without tracking focus change? I don't see any reason to look for `onFocusChangeListener`

Answer (score 1):

At first of all i'll recommend you not to create `textWatcher` in `onFocusChange` method because it doesn't matter constantly create it  when `onFocusChange` will be called, 
and then i want to ask why are you want to remove `textWatchers`, because if your `EditText` won't have focus it's the same, `textWatcher` will not work